How can I test my Flutter code on an iOS emulator using Android Studio while working on a Windows machine?
In Android Studio, I am testing my Flutter code on an Android emulator, but I want to test it on iOS as well. How can I do this on a Windows machine?
If you're testing your Flutter code on an Android emulator in Android Studio but want to test it on an iOS emulator while using a Windows machine,
Searching for a way to add an iOS emulator to Android Studio or Windows.
Exploring third-party tools or plugins that might enable iOS testing on Windows.
A straightforward method to emulate iOS devices directly on a Windows machine.

You cannot. iOS simulators require macOS, but you may be able to tell Flutter to use the iOS look and feel
